# Intercepting Operation Calls

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to intercept operation calls? I want to call another operation every time someone calls a Modal operation (`bpy.ops.transform.translate`) -- I need to get a callback when it starts and when it finishes to run a complementary script. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think so. There are some [handlers](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.app.handlers.html) that you can setup but not for every operator. One possibility might be to create a new operator and link it to the shortcuts so it runs instead of the original, then call the original in the middle of your new operator. Your probably better off writing an operator the user can choose to use instead of the normal one.

Comment: That was the exactly conclusion that i got for now. But as i can want to use a custom transformation, it only will be accessible for hotkeys and not in the manipulators or in the original Tool Shelf "Transform" Panel. Any troughs about it?